# "Load more comments" link, get data in reversed order with infinite scroll pagination

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to create a system of comments that works in a reversed order, from the most recent to the older one, but I have some issue with the logic and I would need some help.

Let's say my database contains a total of 4 comments right now:

```
['comment1', 'comment2', 'comment3', 'comment4'];
```

Let's say the client only loads comments 2 per 2, ordered from the most recent. So I will send a request to the server to return 2 comments (limit 2) from the beginning (offset 0). So far so good, I get the following:

```
['comment3', 'comment4']
```

While those 2 comments are displayed on the client, another user added a comment in the database. It now looks like this:

```
['comment1', 'comment2', 'comment3', 'comment4', 'comment5'];
```

When the client request to load more comments, it will request a limit 2, offset 2, which would be the following:

```
['comment2', 'comment3'];
```

Here is my issue. The comment 3 has already been loaded and would be duplicated on the client side. And the comment 5 will never be loaded.

So my question is how this can be properly handled? With the number of comments changing, offsets become difficult to manage.

I was also thinking of to get the comments per date instead of offset, but makes thing pretty complicated.

What would be the best solution to manage this?

Thanks

Comment: You can store in the HTML or as a Javascript value the datetime or id of the last comment, then when you load comments you can ask the server to send you the *old* and the *new* comments that were published after that datetime or id.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of comment 3's ID, then do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id<x LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2
```

(assuming you would next want to show comments 1 and 2.  You can tweak the comparison to achieve different results)

Comment: That would work for comment 1 and 2, but how could I know there is a comment 5?

Comment: Good question (and perhaps more of a UI one than a programming one if I understand correctly?).  A lot of sites (Tumblr comes to mind) don't seem to care about comment 5.  I've seen others that show some kind of "see new comments" button (StackOverflow).  Facebook and Instagram show the most recent few and make you paginate upwards, prioritizing the most recent comments over the older ones.  Other sites allow votes and prioritize that way.  Depends on what you want.

Comment: What is `x`? How is this value declared?